# extract a sub-matrix when the number of rows may be one

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to extract a sub-matrix of a larger matrix, containing only the first `n` rows:

```
> first.rows <- function(x, n) {
+   x[1:n,]
+ }
> x <- matrix(1:6, 3, 2)
> first.rows(x, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
```

The naive approach, shown above, works nicely unless `n` is less than two:

```
> first.rows(x, 1)
[1] 1 4
```

For `n == 1`, I suddenly get a vector and not a matrix!  I can work around this by using `matrix(x[1:n,], n, ncol(x))`, but this looks unnecessarily convoluted.  Is there a way to solve this problem without the matrix-vector-matrix round-trip?  (Maybe even working for `n == 0`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use `drop = FALSE` for cases where there is only a single row as by default `[` (please check `?Extract`) it uses `drop = TRUE` unlike `subset`

```
first.rows <- function(x, n) {
   x[seq_len(n),, drop = FALSE]
}
```

In addition to that, it is better to have `seq_len(n)` instead of `1:n` for special cases where one can have `n=0`